# New GoDaddy SSL cert on the same Tomcat server fails?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

It's time to renew the certificate.  I followed the instructions from GoDaddy using the same CSR as last time (they pre-fill it).

https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5239/generating-a-csr-and-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-tomcat-4-x5-x6-x7-x

created the new file which I then uploaded to the server and replaced my old one.

now when I navigate to the server https://www.multiplex.io - I get `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

```
DSA002574:multiplex-godaddy-ssl mike.borozdin$ curl -Iv https://www.multiplex.io
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.multiplex.io/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 23.102.131.54...
* Connected to www.multiplex.io (23.102.131.54) port 443 (#0)
* SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved.  The issue was that you need to use the original keystore that was used to create the request, creating a new store from just the certificates that GoDaddy gives you in a zip file won't contain the private key.  The steps to follow are:

1) you might need to remove the old root certificate and import the new one from GoDaddy
2) you will then need to update the tomcat certificate with the renewed one.

You will also need to verify that at the end the private key is indeed in the keystore.